# UCMA based VoiceXML - the <goto> and <log> tags

Tags: c#, ivr, voicexml, ucma

I've written a basic IVR system using UCMA 3.0.   It recieves an incoming call then uses the following class to execute a VXML script:

```
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.AudioVideo.VoiceXml.Browser
```

First question - I currently have a large script that does all sorts of things.  I'd like to break this script up into smaller pieces and call them using the **<goto>** tag.  This is not working.  I'm trying to call a second script using:

```
<goto next="next_page.vxml"/>
```

I've tried many different variations of calling the second script file, without success.  I always get a '**error.badfetch**' error.  Does the <goto> tag actually work in UCMA 3.0?  How?

Second question - where can i find the output of the **<log>** tag?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: error.badfetch indicates that the vxml browser attempted to retrieve the vxml document but was not able to. Does the error message show the complete URL for the document that the badfetch occurs on. If so, try putting that URL into a web browser and see if you can display the document.

Comment: yes, the error message contains a URL that the browser attempted to fetch, however it just mirrors the URL that i specify in the <goto> tag.  I've tried many different variations on relative and absolute paths for the URL.

Comment: Some VoiceXML interpreters raise a badfetch if the target document does not parse.

Comment: To eliminate any parsing issues, as @qawi pointed out, try loading that document as the initial document and see what happens. Another suggestion is to use the submit tag instead of the goto tag to load a new document. Although the vxml spec indicates that the goto tag can be used to load a new document I tend to use it just for navigation within a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VoiceXML the **goto** tag is used to **go to another form only**. I doubt that **next_page.vxml** is the name of any form you created. Use this instead:

```
<submit next="next_page.vxml"/>
```

Or use the name of a **form** in the VoiceXML document.

To find out more about the support for VoiceXML in UCMA read this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh243693%28v=office.14%29.aspx (it states that VoiceXML 2.0 is supported, so the **goto** tag should work when used correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't found <log>'s output, you should change output target of error message.

For example.

```
<error>
    <prompt>Error massage is &quot;<value expr="_message" />&quot;.</prompt>
</error>
```

You can listen error message, when IVR raised error event.